# Stored procedure in SSIS Lookup Transformation Editor

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis

Can you use a stored procedure as the source for Lookup Transaction because it seems to fail on the EXEC statement?

Comment: Where exactly are you putting `EXEC procedure_name`? Try under *Modify the SQL statement* [on the `Advanced` tab](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189962.aspx). If that's where you are doing it, then the error message is probably telling you the truth - it needs to be a table, a view, or a SQL statement (e.g. a `SELECT` query, not an `EXEC`).

Comment: @AaronBertrand. EXEC procedure_name is the the query. Found that if I replace that with SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY() in the Connection Tab that it works. Don't like having to use OPENQUERY.

Comment: Yeah that is an ugly workaround.

Comment: @AaronBertrand But necessary because the SSIS package uses the same lookup 32 times and I would hate it if I had to ever change the logic.

Comment: But what does the procedure do that couldn't be done in either a view or a table-valued function?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks for showing me my blinders. It was vendor provided code. The stored procedure could just as easily be a view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest trying to put the stored procedure logic into a view or table-valued function, which could then be referenced in the lookup.

If that can't be done, then you can use the ugly workaround you already discovered:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LoopBackServer, N'EXEC db.dbo.procedurename;');
```

Comment: The other way around this is to switch from no cache to full cache. Full cache will allow you to use a stored procedure.